# Google play license check

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I've Komodo 10 chess engine in my old Smartphone but when I shareit with my new Smartphone I've received this message:

> Application Not Licensed
>   . 
>   This application is not licensed. please purchase it from android market.
>   Exit BuyApp

What I've to do now!?
(there is a problem here, I can't buy any app from google because, it is not available in my country)

Comment: Did you purchase this app with a different email address than currently using?

Comment: @beeshyams From the beginning there was the app on my  old phone

Comment: Just to be clear - is it the same Gmail? If it is, then you may have to contact the company

Comment: [Should there be a problem with license activation, Komodo will not be functional on your device. Please contact Komodo Chess support and we'll get you sorted out.](https://komodochess.com/komodo-8-playstore.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the app came with your phone, it's only licensed for the phone it came on. The phone manufacturer paid the software author for the right to use it on that phone only. If you want to use it on your new phone, you'll have to buy it this time.